# I need help for a flutter project here when I add checkboxlisttile I got white screen

Tags: flutter

This is my code

```dart
class Signup extends StatefulWidget {
  const Signup({super.key});
  @override
  State<Signup> createState() => _SignupState();
}

class _SignupState extends State<Signup> {
  bool? _chacked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.chevron_left,
            color: Color(0xFF032272),
            size: 40,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        title: Text(
          'New Account',
          style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF032272), fontSize: 30),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: AssetImage("assets/background_image.png"))),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 100, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Name",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF032272),
                      fontSize: 22,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 340,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          border:
                              Border.all(width: 3, color: Color(0xFFA9BCFE)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: 'UserName',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFA9BCFE)),
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Password",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF032272),
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Container(
                        width: 340,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          border:
                              Border.all(width: 3, color: Color(0xFFA9BCFE)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: 'UserName',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFA9BCFE)),
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Email",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF032272),
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Container(
                        width: 340,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          border:
                              Border.all(width: 3, color: Color(0xFFA9BCFE)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: 'UserName',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFA9BCFE)),
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "You Are :",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF032272),
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              /*CheckboxListTile(                                   title: Text("psychologist"),                                   value: _chacked,                                   onChanged: (value) {                                     setState(() {                                       _chacked = value!;                                     });                                     Visibility(                                         visible: _chacked ?? false,                                          child: const TextField( decoration: InputDecoration(                                           hintText: 'ps',                                          ),)                                         );                                   }),*/
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the `CheckBoxListTile` is inside the `Row<Column` which is causing the constrains issue. You can wrap with a Expanded widget to get available space.

```dart
Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CheckboxListTile(
              ....
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
),
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can checkout https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints